# Can I create a multi-file zip archive from memory buffer using Poco?

Tags: c++, zip, poco-libraries

I'm thinking of moving my project to Poco. I'd like to start by moving some of the code over to see what Poco is like and capable of.

One of the things I need to do is write several memory buffers as a multi-file zip archive on a disk. i.e. char buffer[] -> DEFLATE Zip archive. No intermediate files are written to disk.

Currently I use zlib to achieve this. I've also done the same with http://libarchive.github.com/.

Can I do this in Poco?

I've looked at the examples, and it appears that it only takes a file name as an input, not a (char *) pointer to a buffer.

http://pocoproject.org/docs/ZipUserGuide.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can add raw memory buffers to a zip file with [POCO](http://pocoproject.org).

The following running code shows how, with the help of the zero-copy [`Poco::MemoryInputStream`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.MemoryInputStream.html). You could do the same with [`std::istringstream`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/), but in that case you would have a memory copy from your buffer to the underlying [`std::stringbuf`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringbuf/).

```
#include <Poco/Exception.h>
#include <Poco/Zip/Compress.h>
#include <Poco/DateTime.h>
#include <Poco/MemoryStream.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

/*
 * Compress multiple buffers to a zip archive, each buffer gets its filename.
 * Raw data, you need to do the serialization yourself.
 * To verify the data: unzip data.zip && hexdump -C buf1 && hexdump -C buf2
 */
void f(const char* buf1, size_t buf1len, const char* buf2, size_t buf2len) {
    std::ofstream ostr("data.zip", std::ios::binary);
    Poco::Zip::Compress compress(ostr, true);

    // Poco::MemoryInputStream is a zero-copy implementation of std::istream :-)
    Poco::MemoryInputStream mis1(buf1, buf1len);
    compress.addFile(mis1, Poco::DateTime(), "buf1");

    Poco::MemoryInputStream mis2(buf2, buf2len);
    compress.addFile(mis2, Poco::DateTime(), "buf2");

    compress.close();
    ostr.close();
}

int main() {
    const char buf1[] = "binary\0buffer"; size_t buf1len = sizeof(buf1);
    const char buf2[] = "BIN\0BUF";       size_t buf2len = sizeof(buf2);
    try {
        f(buf1, buf1len, buf2, buf2len);
        return 0;
    } catch (Poco::Exception& e) {
        cout << e.displayText() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

In my opinion POCO is a wonderful, lightweight, modern, easy-to-understand C++ library, you will find yourself quickly at ease with it.

Comment: Too bad you can't decompress without intermediate files

Comment: is there any option to add more data to 'mis1' stream. say you can the data in chunks, is it possible to compress it in chunks ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly add a file to a zip without having to have an actual file. While you can't pass a `char *` directly, there is an [`addFile()`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Zip.Compress.html#21666) that takes a `std::istream`, from which to read the data.